# How to prevent form on submit behavior in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to get an .click() event and prevent form from behaving as it was initially designed and make my own changes and submit. How is it possible?

**EDIT:** Form input actually has an onclick defined behavior. I need to redefine it somehow.

**EDIT:** Some code

```
<form action='link' method='get'>
   <input type="image" name="name" id="id" class="class" onclick="this.form.action='some_link'" title="Title" value="" src="image.gif">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263852/prevent-form-redirect-or-refresh-on-submit or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699065/submitting-a-form-on-enter-with-jquery or many many others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    // Some code
});
```

I think it's enough.

Comment: So if I have lets say onclick="this.form.action='somelink'" it will execute and afterwards suggested code (Some code) will?

Comment: I'm not sure. What is sure is form will be submitted. You can use e.prevendDefault(); and this.submit() if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want it to submit the form, `return false` at the end of your click function.  If you want to submit the form, use the form element and call the submit function on it:

```
$('#myFormID').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this (haven't tested it but it should work)

```
form = $("#yourform");
button = $("#yoursubmit");
button.click(function(){
             dosomething();
             form.submit();
             return false;});
```

Comment: What about users who submit form typing enter?

Comment: @MatTheCat: The OP specifically asked for a click event. This solution can be applied to a generic button, even if it resides outside the form.