# Angular+Jquery - Programmatic form submit causes redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, angularjs

I'm trying to write a form which has ngsSubmit.
Pressing Enter and clicking the submit button works as expected (calling the method I provided for ng-submit and that's that).

However, I also want in some cases to do some preprocessing before actually submitting, so I tried using JQuery's submit() to programmatically trigger the submit.

This causes the ng-submit handler to fire, AND also sends the form normally refreshing the whole page.

Any ideas how to get around this or why it happens???

Example here ("click me" shows the bad behavior)
http://jsfiddle.net/Yf5tf/

```
<form ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="submitMe()" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!"></input>
    <div ng-click="progSubmit()">click me</div>
</form>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $element, $timeout) {
    $scope.submitMe = function() { alert ("hi"); };
    $scope.progSubmit = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            var inputElem =  $element.find("input");
            angular.element(inputElem[0].form).submit();
          }, 0);
    };
});
```

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent form redirect OR refresh on submit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263852/prevent-form-redirect-or-refresh-on-submit)

Comment: do you need to stop the default behavior of the submit?  Submit submits, btw.  It will refresh.  Do you want to.... do an ajax post or something (a fake submit, kind of) and preventDefault() or return false in the `$('#submit').click(function(){...})` area ( or on the `$('#form').submit(function(){...});`)

Comment: Couldn't you just do your preprocessing within `submitMe()`?

Comment: Gloomy, normally angular intercepts the submit (ng-submit directive) and reroutes it to the method I provide. However, it does not work with programmatic submit. I see no reason why clicking a type="submit" button would be different then programmatically submitting.

Michael, there are a few elements in the form that I'd like to trigger the submit (autocomplete text for example), so I'm not clear as to how I can do that.

Comment: BTW, it's not a duplicate of the other question as this is more an angular issue.

Comment: One more thing I realized is that if there's a location with a hashtag (eg: mysite.com/#....) the page reload doesn't happen and the ng-submit action is called as expected.

Comment: Looks like working as intended.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So... in case anyone has the same issue.

The solution is to trigger submit using JQuery. 
Ideally it would be:

```
angular.element($scope.inputElem[0].form).trigger('submit');
```

However, there is some bug in Angular, so the current work around I found is this:

```
angular.element($scope.inputElem[0].form).find('[type=submit]').trigger('click');
```

Cheers.

Comment: This is *HORRIBLE*! Thanks for doing the work and posting the answer though, I was going crazy until I found this.

Comment: By horrible I meant that when I started writing my directive I thought it was going to be a lovely little call like this: `elem.form.submit()`