# javascript form submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

As according to the advice at [Prevent form redirect OR refresh on submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263852/prevent-form-redirect-or-refresh-on-submit) , I have my form which is

```
<form id="editingForm">
  Line height (between 10 and 60): 
  <input type="number" id="LineHeightEntry" name="LineHeightEntry" min="10" max="60" value="30">
  <input type="submit" id="submitLineChange" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In a file called test.html.  The javascript is

```
$('#editingForm').submit(function(){
  alert("abc");
  return false;
});
```

The intent is to have the function be called, and then javascript can do something to the page, but the page is not reloaded or redirected elsewhere.  However, instead what I get is say I set LineHeightEntry to 40 and hit submit.  Then it redirects to test.html?LineHeightEntry=40.  Why does it do that?

edit - The file is at http://probuling.net/sandbox/test.html

Comment: are you programmatically setting `action` attribute in your `form`...as I dont see it

Comment: need to set method attribute for form too...

Comment: It doesn't redirect: http://jsfiddle.net/3RAPj/

Comment: You do have jQuery loaded, right?

Comment: I do, and even the suggestion with replacing the jquery with non jquery still redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <form id="editingForm" action="toto">
      Line height (between 10 and 60): 
      <input type="number" id="LineHeightEntry" name="LineHeightEntry" min="10" max="60" value="30">
  <input type="submit" id="submitLineChange" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
$('#editingForm').submit(function(event)
{
  alert("abc");
event.preventDefault(); // if you want to disable the action
  return false;

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @user2963178 I think the problem was that you were calling that js before the DOM was loaded.  Therefore, you were trying to attach an event to an element that didn't exist yet.

Comment: Well this example works, but when I added the event.preventDefault() into the script on my main page at http://probuling.net/sandbox/test.html it still redirects... and jquery is included so I'm still as confused as before.  It didn't help that it actually took about 5 minutes of ftping before ipage would stop replacing my file with a blank file lol...

Comment: and when it redirects it redirects to an old version of the page but of the same name... which does not have jquery, sometimes has different text on the page, and has an old css file which is no longer included.

Comment: Patrick Q is right, you need to put the Javascript binding code AFTER your html form. I just did it, it works perfectly

Comment: Ah I didn't understand what he meant.  Yes now it works with that change.

Comment: there is also "event" missing in the call of the function... function(event){} instead of function(){}

Answer (score 0):

Add action attribute to the form or you are just refreshing the page on submit.

```
<form id="editingForm" action="/another/url">
```

I would recommend learning how to use normal form submit before even try using Javascript. Any input with name attribute will be appended to the URL since you have no action and default method is set to GET.

Comment: That's not the issue.  By default the page would post back on itself.

Comment: I know how to use normal form submit.  What I want is for it to not refresh the page or load any other page.  Basically the input fields let the user modify the CSS of some elements on the page, and a textarea lets the user modify the contents of those elements as well.  So when the form is submitted I want it to just run the javascript functions, which do all the work.  I have it all working in the sense that I tied it to an onclick of a button, and so it works nicely with that.  However I can't get it to work with the form, so that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Submit function callback is working fine. Checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/935V6/

Answer (score 0):

remove line return false;

This prevent default event.
Read more detail:
http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Answer (score 0):

try doing it without jQuery. Also, try using the event.preventDefault

```
document.querySelector('#editingForm').onsubmit = function(event) {
  alert('abc');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
};
```

Comment: that doesn't work either.  I'm putting the url of the file up in the OP.  http://probuling.net/sandbox/test.html

Comment: I just tried your test page and it works as expected for me (on Chrome). What browser are you using? Did you disable javascript?