# How to deny form from dissapearing when submitting/onsearch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read about 10-15 different similar stackoverflow questions but none seems to do it for me so I figured I'll get my issue out there.

I have this html:

```
     <form>
     <input type="search"/>
     </form>
```

Which creates a textarea, if I then click inside of this textarea and type something (don't need to) and then clicks enter the form (with textarea) dissapears on the second attempt I click enter everytime.

Same goes if I use `type="submit"`.

What happends is that page reloads and then form is gone. 
Note that I need to have the type as search and cant change it to anything else.

I've tried the `preventdefault()` in the javascript trying to deny page reload without any further success.

How do I make to it so that the form doesn't dissapear when clicking enter?

Comment: Prevent enter from submitting the form: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1977126/769971

Comment: This is what finally worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263852/prevent-form-redirect-or-refresh-on-submit

Answer (score 0):

Really weird interaction in your problem, but you can always do `<form onSubmit="return false;">`

And then when you want to submit the from, you need to do it through some other method.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tovg38v/